# React bootstrap not installing

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I tried installing react bootstrap on my machine for my new project using this 
npm install react-bootstrap --save

but i keep getting these errors

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OLAOSEBIKAN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-22T20_05_27_792Z-debug.log
```

I have create-react-app working fine

Comment: What version of npm are you using? (i.e. npm -v in your console). Also what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10
npm v 5.6.0

Comment: .....and I just got it installed.
 I used npm install bootstrap

Comment: are you behind a proxy at all? This might help (official GitHub issue) https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8151

Comment: Everything is fine now, thanks